# SQL: How to delete Millions of Records from a Table without disturbing the server

Tags: sql-server

A software of ours ran out of control and did put in millions/billions of uneccecary records in a table.
How can I delete them without disturbing the server?

This is what I have tried:
- setting transaction log to simple
- deleting them in batches in a script
- putting the virtual machine on a SSD
It still took 3 weeks before I aborted.

I don't really want to copy the data I want to keep and then delete the table.

Comment: Does your table have indexes? You should drop/disable them first. what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: Just as a side note, if you had the DB in Full mode and put the data file and t-log file on separate SSD's, built an index on the col you are searching for to delete from, and then run a loop job that commits after X rows, that may help. It will still take a long time, but that could help. Later doing a partitioned table would be helpful, especially if it's 2016 because you could truncate partitions. In 2012, you can at least drop partitions.

Comment: Note that switching the recovery model to SIMPLE does mean that you lose the ability to do point-in-time recovery for the whole database. If the transaction log got too full, then try increasing the frequency of transaction log updates, so space in the log is cleared more frequently. Also, as noted elsewhere, smaller batches let the transaction log clear the data for each batch faster (and of course make each batch's data smaller).

Answer (score 3):

You need a way to estimate the amount of time that your process will take. I also recommend a simple mechanism for logging how much progress that your code makes. That way you can avoid surprises when it runs 3 weeks when you weren't expecting it to. So start by getting that estimate. You say "millions/billions" of rows in the question but there's a big difference between the two. Which is it? You'll also want to design your looping code in a way such that the last batch takes about as long as the first batch. That way you'll get predictable performance. I don't know what kind of criteria you're using to identify bad rows so I can't give any advice for that.

The basic strategy that you want to use for the delete depends on the structure of the table and the percentage of bad rows in it:

1. If you're deleting the majority of rows from a heap then realistically you can't design a looping paradigm that runs in constant time. The best I know if is to delete the top `N` rows in a loop and to stop when you delete less than `N` rows. Be sure to use the `TABLOCK` hint when doing the `DELETE`. Otherwise SQL Server will not free up pages from deleted rows which means that the final batch will essentially do a full scan of all of the previous rows in the table.
2. If you're deleting the majority of rows from a clustered table then loop over the clustered index. Avoid looping over the same row more than once.
3. If you're deleting a minority of rows from a heap or clustered table, consider creating a nonclustered index that will help identify the next batch of rows to delete. If possible you could consider a filtered index so you don't do more work than necessary when creating it. Avoid looping over the same row more than once.

There are a few things that might improve the speed of your process:

- The delete part of the query will run single threaded so increasing CPU single core speed and getting at least 2 dedicated CPUs for your VM will help. If your VM is oversubscribed for resources that can lead to unpredictable performance. Here I'm assuming that the query to identify rows to delete is simple enough that it will be run entirely in serial. If not the number of CPUs available to SQL Server may become important.
- Increasing the disk speed of your data and log files can help. As a general rule of thumb, switching to simple recovery model will not reduce the amount of data logged to the transaction log except if minimal logging is used. Minimal logging cannot be used for DELETE statements. All you gained by switching was not having to do transaction log backups.
- Disabling all nonclustered indexes before doing the delete will help. Rebuild them after all of the bad rows are deleted.

The fastest delete is the one that you don't have to do. You said that you don't want to have to copy the data. That's fine, I assume you have good reasons for that. But know that you might be passing on a solution that runs in hours as opposed to days or weeks.

Answer (score 2):

if you are running the deletes in batches, do you have an index on column that you are using to chunk up the process?  IF there is no index and the query is resorting to full table scans to try and find the data that should be deleted, you could be adding a lot of time to the process.

Unfortunately backing up the good data then dropping/truncating the table is probably your best bet. You could always rename the existing table and create a new table to do this rather then trying to extract just the data you need to keep.  This way if you found your initial load of data was lacking, you still have everything to go back to for a second look.

Comment: Problem is, the process needs to run on a production database that's in use 24/7. I'm hoping to get this down with no downtime, but sounds like I might need to schedule some maintenance.

Comment: There is an non-clustered index on the table though, including the columns I'm doing the lookup with (I think, will need to double check).

Comment: Oops I thought this was a response to my question on stack overflow.